# Trying to import .OBJ from Magicavoxel to Blender, but it imports as a single large object?

Tags: objects, import, obj

I want to import a model from Magicavoxel into Blender that already has the desired colors and effects applied to them.

I imported it easy enough, but it seems to have imported as a single object which I can only edit as a whole. Also, while my colors transferred over, none of the light effects (certain areas glowing) were translated into Blender. I was hoping to fix this in Blender, but I can't select individual pieces of my build - it's all one object now.

It doesn't seem like exporting/importing with a different file format (such as .ply) helps in any way.

Is there anyway to either import my glow effects and lighting from Magicavoxel to Blender, or, import from Magicavoxel to Blender and retain each build piece as a single object (as it is in Magicavoxel) so I can edit them separately?

Please also note, while I consider myself computer-savvy, I am a beginner at both of these programs (less than 20 hours each of experience), so please spell things out for me.

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately a plugin to import a .vox file without the need to convert to .obj https://github.com/RichysHub/MagicaVoxel-VOX-importer . Instructions on how to use it and caveats are on that page but will reproduce installation and basic usage instructions here:

Download `io_scene_vox.py` from the github page and install it into Blender.

In order to enable the add-on, you will need to have Testing add-ons visible within the Blender Preferences menu.

[image]

With the add-on installed and enabled, the importer can be accessed from File > Import > MagicaVoxel (.vox)

[image]

This add-on imports each voxel of the original model as an individual cube primitive. This opens up the use of voxel models for projects such as physics simulations.

[image]